# Where is the crowbar in black mesa?

Tags: black-mesa

I'm stuck in the Unforeseen Consequences level. I made it all the way back to the tram platform but I haven't found a crowbar yet. Any hints on where to look for it?

Comment: Finding the crowbar isn't the objective of the game, as much as that may sound confusing. Just move on without it.

Comment: Finding the crowbar is one of most pinnacle events in Half-Life. It may not be absolutely necessary, but I can't imagine the game without it. I did find it once I figured out where to go to end the chapter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just keep going. The crowbar is a little bit later in Black Mesa than it was in the original Half-Life, but it's impossible to miss it and it's not that far away. It's pretty linear at the beginning, so just go whichever way is available until you get it.

Answer (score 4):

Head back to the main entrance ( the terminal where the guard complains of the system crashing) and find the ventilator shaft blown open. Crowbar is wedged in the door handles.

Just run past all the zombies you first encounter - you won't have enough bullets for all of them

Comment: I ran past there about four times before I found that ventilation shaft. My memory of HL 10 years isn't as great as I hoped!